# Get User location alert does not stay on screen in iOS 8

Tags: ios, locationmanager

I am trying to get authorization from user before fetching his location. I am using this code for that:

```
        self.locationManager  = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
        if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
            // iOS8+
            // Sending a message to avoid compile time error
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
        [self showIndicatorView];
        self.getCityService = [[GetCitiesService alloc] initServiceWithDelegate:self isLocalCall:NO];
        [self.getCityService fetchCities];
```

I see the alert on screen but before I allow it or not, it disappear form screen and app is not authorized.

I want my code to stop until user gives permission.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently in iOS 8 SDK, requestAlwaysAuthorization (for background location) or requestWhenInUseAuthorization (location only when foreground) call on CLLocationManager is needed before starting location updates.

There also needs to be NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in Info.plist with a message to be displayed in the prompt. Adding these solved my problem.

Hope it helps someone else.

EDIT: For more extensive information, have a look at: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Comment: Which xCode version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You code looks really weird, since you seem to be calling the `requestAlwaysAuthorization` twice. Once on `self.locationManager` and once via the `sendAction`.

You code should look like:

```
    self.locationManager  = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        // iOS8+
        // Sending a message to avoid compile time error
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
```

Comment: I have done this before but alert get disappeared before any input

Comment: Well you are calling the methods twice which may cause unexpected behavior.